# fetching name and age from a text file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, data-extraction, google-natural-language

I have a .txt file from which I have to fetch name and age.
The .txt file has data in the format like:

```
Age: 71 . John is 47 years old. Sam; Born: 05/04/1989(29).
Kenner is a patient Age: 36 yrs    Height: 5 feet 1 inch; weight is 56 kgs. 
This medical record is 10 years old. 

Output 1: John, Sam, Kenner
Output_2: 47, 29, 36
```

I am using the regular expression to extract data. For example, for age, I am using the below regular expressions:

```
re.compile(r'age:\s*\d{1,3}',re.I)

re.compile(r'(age:|is|age|a|) \s*\d{1,3}(\s|y)',re.I)

re.compile(r'.* Age\s*:*\s*[0-9]+.*',re.I)

re.compile(r'.* [0-9]+ (?:year|years|yrs|yr) \s*',re.I)
```

I will apply another regular expression to the output of these regular expressions to extract the numbers. The problem is with these regular expressions, I am also getting the data which I do not want. For example

```
This medical record is 10 years old.
```

I am getting '10' from the above sentence which I do not want.
I only want to extract the names of people and their age. I want to know what should be the approach? I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: You can't do it this way. For this to work you have to know exactly what the form is for  NAME and AGE and has to have a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: @sln Thanks for the help. I got your point but the data is random as you can see there is not a unique format in the document. I cannot have 1 to 1 relationship. I want to know is there any other approach like Natural Language Processing or some other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [Cloud Data Loss Prevention API](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/). Here is a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/dlp) with examples. This is what you'll likely want.

```
def inspect_string(project, content_string, info_types,
                   min_likelihood=None, max_findings=None, include_quote=True):
    """Uses the Data Loss Prevention API to analyze strings for protected data.
    Args:
        project: The Google Cloud project id to use as a parent resource.
        content_string: The string to inspect.
        info_types: A list of strings representing info types to look for.
            A full list of info type categories can be fetched from the API.
        min_likelihood: A string representing the minimum likelihood threshold
            that constitutes a match. One of: 'LIKELIHOOD_UNSPECIFIED',
            'VERY_UNLIKELY', 'UNLIKELY', 'POSSIBLE', 'LIKELY', 'VERY_LIKELY'.
        max_findings: The maximum number of findings to report; 0 = no maximum.
        include_quote: Boolean for whether to display a quote of the detected
            information in the results.
    Returns:
        None; the response from the API is printed to the terminal.
    """

    # Import the client library.
    import google.cloud.dlp

    # Instantiate a client.
    dlp = google.cloud.dlp.DlpServiceClient()

    # Prepare info_types by converting the list of strings into a list of
    # dictionaries (protos are also accepted).
    info_types = [{'name': info_type} for info_type in info_types]

    # Construct the configuration dictionary. Keys which are None may
    # optionally be omitted entirely.
    inspect_config = {
        'info_types': info_types,
        'min_likelihood': min_likelihood,
        'include_quote': include_quote,
        'limits': {'max_findings_per_request': max_findings},
      }

    # Construct the `item`.
    item = {'value': content_string}

    # Convert the project id into a full resource id.
    parent = dlp.project_path(project)

    # Call the API.
    response = dlp.inspect_content(parent, inspect_config, item)

    # Print out the results.
    if response.result.findings:
        for finding in response.result.findings:
            try:
                if finding.quote:
                    print('Quote: {}'.format(finding.quote))
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            print('Info type: {}'.format(finding.info_type.name))
            print('Likelihood: {}'.format(finding.likelihood))
    else:
        print('No findings.')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes, DLP would be very helpful. I will read more about it. In my case, the labels like Name: Age: are not mentioned everywhere, so might be it would not work there.

Comment: What I have thought to tackle this problem: There is a text file avalable online containing 90k names. I will make a search between my files and that file to check all the names.

Comment: DLP does names and age. Here is a list of all InfoType it'll detect: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/infotypes-reference

Comment: Is it possible to get connected with you through email or LinkedIn?